# Dice Rolling - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am just starting with Java programming and wrote a program to roll an x-sided dice x-times. The sides and the number of rolls are defined by user input. The program gives out the absolute and relative frequencies of each number in a `JTable` format. Everything works well until you choose large numbers for the sides and number of rolls. I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but can't find any respective errors in the code.

```
package rolling;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RollDice extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6332129624300946462L;
    JTable jt;
    int i, k, j; //Counter for loops

    /*========== CONSTRUCTOR CREATES TABLE OBJECT ==========*/  
    public RollDice(int[] trial, int[] outcomes, int[] dice_numbers,
    int[] count, float[] Rel_frequencies){

        String[] columnNames = {"Number of trial", "Outcome", "Dice Numbers",
                                "Absolute Frequencies", "Relative Frequencies"};

        Object[][] input = new Object[trial.length][columnNames.length];

        for (i=0; i<trial.length; i++){
            input[i][0] = trial[i];
        }
        for (i=0; i<outcomes.length; i++){
            input[i][1] = outcomes[i];
        }
        for (i=0; i<dice_numbers.length; i++){
            input[i][2] = dice_numbers[i];
        }
        for (i=0; i<count.length; i++){
            input[i][3] = count[i];
        }
        for (i=0; i<Rel_frequencies.length; i++){
            input[i][4] = Rel_frequencies[i];
        }

        /*Checking the outcome!
        for (i=0; i<trial.length; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for (k=0; k<columnNames.length; k++){
            System.out.printf("%d\t", input[i][k]);
            }
        }*/
        jt = new JTable(input,columnNames)
        {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean isCellEditable(int input, int columns)
            {
                return false;
            }
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int input,
            int columns){
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, input, columns);

                if (input %2 == 0){
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else{
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }
                if (isCellSelected(input, columns)){
                    c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                return c;
                }
        };

        jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 600));
        jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt);
        add(jps);
    }

    public static int[] roll_dice(int sides, int rolls){
        int[] outcomes = new int[rolls];
        int i; //Counter for accessing array position (element)
        for (i=0; i<rolls; i++){
            outcomes[i] = (int)(1 + Math.random() * sides);
        }
        return outcomes;
    }

    public static int[] Frequency_count(int[] outcomes, int sides){
        int[] count = new int[sides];
        int i;
        int j, k = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=sides; i++){
            for(j=0; j<outcomes.length; j++){
                if (outcomes[j] == i){
                    count[k]++;
                }
            }
            //System.out.printf("%d \t %d\n",i, count[k]);
            k++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static float[] Relative_frequencies(int[] count, int sides, 
    int rolls){
        int i;
        float[] Array = new float [sides];
        for(i=0; i<sides; i++){
            Array[i] = (float)count[i] / rolls * 100;
            //String.format("%.3f", (float)Array[i]);
            //System.out.printf("%d \t %.2f\n",i+1, Array[i]);
        }
        return Array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*=========USER INPUT via GUI: DECISION ON HOW MANY TIMES
           THE DICE IS ROLLED===*
         *=========     AND HOW MANY SIDES THE DICE HAS  ===*/

        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of sides
        of the dice");
        String sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of rolls");

        int sides = Integer.parseInt(fn); // number of sides
        int rolls = Integer.parseInt(sn); // number of rolls

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled a " + sides + "
        sided dice " + rolls + " times!", "User Input",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );

        /*=========GENERATING RANDOM NUMBERS (ROLLING THE DICE) WITH 
         "roll_dice" method==========
         *=========  AND COUNTING THE NO. OF TRIALS     ==========*/
        int[] outcomes = roll_dice(sides, rolls);
        int[] trial = new int[rolls];
        int[] dice_numbers = new int[sides];

        int i, k;
        k = 1;
        for(i=0; i<rolls; i++){
            trial[i] = k;
            //System.out.println(i + " " + k);
            k++;
        }
        k = 1;
        for(i=0; i<sides; i++){
            dice_numbers[i] = k;
            //System.out.println(i + " " + k);
            k++;
        }
        /*=========COUNTING THE FREQUENCIES OF EACH NUMBER==========*/
        //System.out.println("ABSOLUTE Frequencies plotted in FUNCTION:");
        int[] count = Frequency_count(outcomes, sides);
        //System.out.println("RELATIVE Frequencies plotted in FUNCTION:");
        float[] Rel_frequencies = Relative_frequencies(count, sides, rolls);


        /*=========CREATING A TABLE FORMAT WITH A JAVA 
        LIBRARY (JTABLE)==========*/
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        RollDice table1 = new RollDice(trial, outcomes, dice_numbers, 
        count, Rel_frequencies);
        jf.setTitle("Absolute and Relative Frequencies of numbers for
        an arbitrary Dice");
        jf.setSize(500, 700);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(table1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line number does the exception occur on?

Comment: When I enter "200" as sides and "100" for my number of rolls I get this error message:<br/>

**Exception in thread "main"<br/> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100<br/>
 at rolling.RollDice.<init>(RollDice.java:36)<br/>
 at rolling.RollDice.main(RollDice.java:162)**<br/>

Thus the error seems to be somewhat related to the number of rolls.<br/>
However, I cannot find any errors in the indicated lines 36 and 162.

Comment: @robby That's the error message:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at rolling.RollDice.<init>(RollDice.java:36)
 at rolling.RollDice.main(RollDice.java:162)**

Comment: Your input array has `rolls` rows, which is less than `sides`. (for your test case with 100 and 200). On line 36, you are looping from `i = 0` till i `i < Rel_frequencies.length`, and `Rel_frequencies.length` is your number of `sides`. Therefore, when `i > rolls`, you are getting an exception, since there does not exist a row in the input array at that index, it only has `100` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this section of code here:

```
Object[][] input = new Object[trial.length][columnNames.length];

for (i=0; i<trial.length; i++){
    input[i][0] = trial[i];
}
for (i=0; i<outcomes.length; i++){
    input[i][1] = outcomes[i];
}
for (i=0; i<dice_numbers.length; i++){
    input[i][2] = dice_numbers[i];
}
for (i=0; i<count.length; i++){
    input[i][3] = count[i];
}
for (i=0; i<Rel_frequencies.length; i++){
    input[i][4] = Rel_frequencies[i];
}
```

You have the `input` 2D array set to a certain size, but then you access it without a second thought.

For instance, look at this:

```
int[] trial = new int[rolls];
int[] dice_numbers = new int[sides];
```

Say the user rolls 2 dices for a 6-sides dice (conventional dice). Then in the third loop, for instance, you access `input[i][2]` where i runs from 0 to 5, however since `trial.length = 2`, you're accessing a non-existing index.

You should review your code so that you only access your arrays according to giving bounds during initialization (I don't know enough of your task to try and suggest something better).

Comment: I think what you addressed is not the main problem of the code. The for loops are created correctly by giving enough space for each element since i used the '.length' operator specifically for the respective array in each for loop.
The problem is, as @RobbyCornelissen pointed out, that the first two arrays 'trial' and 'outcomes' have another size as the other three arrays 'dice_numbers', 'count' and 'Rel_frequencies' unless the user decides to set 'rolls' and 'size' equal.
Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will always face this issue if you have more sides than rolls.

You initialize your `dice_numbers` and `Relative_Frequencies` arrays with a length equal to the number of sides, but the first dimension of your `input` array is only sized to the number of rolls.

Then, the following pieces of code error out because you are trying to store values in positions outside of the dimensions of the `input` array:

```
for (i=0; i<dice_numbers.length; i++){
    input[i][2] = dice_numbers[i];
}
// ...
for (i=0; i<Rel_frequencies.length; i++){
    input[i][4] = Rel_frequencies[i];
}
```

If I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, for a quick fix, dimension your `input` array to whichever is higher: the number of sides or the number of rolls.

However, the conceptual problem with your program seems to be that you're trying to store two different data sets in the same array, i.e. one set of data about the actual rolls and their outcomes, and one set of data about the frequency distribution of the sides.

Splitting these two sets up into two arrays and two data tables would probably go a long way towards resolving the issues you're facing.

Comment: Thanks thats helpful! I didn't see this in the first place although it's quite obvious. Is there a possibility to create non-static multidimensional arrays with flexible element size in Java?

Comment: @StefanStiller `static` or non-`static` doesn't really factor into it. Strictly speaking, there are no flexible-length arrays in Java. You probably want to start looking into Java collections.